# SSH: "You must specify a subsystem to invoke."

Tags: server, bash, ssh

Both a staging and a live WordPress site reside on a DreamHost host. Password-less login has been established from the staging host to the live host, so the command:

```
ssh livehostusername@host
```

At the staging host opens a terminal session at the live host.

An attempt to run the command:

```
ssh livehostusername@host -s < local_script.sh
```

results in the following:

```
You must specify a subsystem to invoke.
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

The script `local_script.sh` is intended to update the live site with exports already uploaded to the live site via scp.

Comment: put the script on the host and call it with `ssh livehostusername@host '/path/to/script.sh'`

Comment: discussion - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments but, IMO, easier to just transfer the script

Comment: Why are you using `-s`?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: sorry I miss you already answer and your link is more complete than my answer.

Comment: @muru Because I didn't know any better! Now I do.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I want to accept your comment as an answer if it becomes one since it arrived earlier.

Comment: That is fine, @olivierb2 took the time to type an answer, fine by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to run a non local script on a remote server, you may have to use the following syntax:

```
/usr/bin/ssh livehostusername@host 'bash /dev/stdin' < local_script.sh
```

If you would like simply to run a command on a remote server, you may use the following systax

```
/usr/bin/ssh livehostusername@host /full_path/local_script.sh
```